# Push back an enemy on trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two gameobjects, one of them is my "hero" an the other one the enemy with a NavMesh, I've managed to make the health system without problems but know when the sword collides with the enemy it seems that the rigidbody is not working or something because I've tried a couple of solutions that I've found on Internet but nothing seem to work. I want the enemy to be pushed once the sword collides with it. I've tried this:

```
public void takeDamage() { 
  // revert rigidbody velocity:
  rigidbody.velocity *= -1;
}
```

Another code

```
float distance = 25.0f;
                if (player.position.x < enemyPosition.position.x) {
                    Vector3 new_position = new Vector3 (distance, enemyPosition.position.y, enemyPosition.position.z);
                    rb.position = new_position;
                }
```

Thanks

Edit:

It seems to be solved with this code:

```
Vector3 new_position = new Vector3 (3.0f, 0f, 0f) + rb.transform.position;
rb.transform.position = new_position;
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when you implement these examples?

Comment: Nothing, the health variable decreases as it should but nothing else happens

Comment: Is there something in your `Update()` method for the enemy that is setting their velocity back to what it was?

Comment: Yes, the SetDestination method from the NavMesh. But the object doesn't even move when it collides with the sword.

Comment: How did you get your rigidbody? With `GetComponent`? Have you tried to set the value very high? Like 10000 or so to make sure it does something?

Comment: Yes, with GetComponent. Now It's working with a very similar code to the one I posted before:

Vector3 new_position = new Vector3 (3.0f, 0f, 0f) + rb.transform.position;
rb.transform.position = new_position;

Answer (score 0):

Test this out

```
   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 1)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Nothing, I get the same result.

Comment: Probably means something is wrong with your mesh or setting on the collision mesh. Try making a two box's and test this code out.